# How can I read headphone' information in iOS device

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a software to check headphone' information on iPad. When I plug a headphone to iPad, I want to read the headphone' information (ex: PID, VID, Serial Number, ...)

If I plug a headphone to MacBook I can see that's information like as [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKXjP.png), I don't know how can I read that's information in IOS? Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: There is no API for this.

Comment: Really, so there's no way I can read that's information if the headphone are plug to iPad, right?

Comment: You can find out when headphones are connected or disconnected by [observing audio route changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes) but you can't get any details of the headphones that are connected.  Remember that older devices with a 3.5mm headphone socket are still supported.  Even in your picture, you don't have any details of the headphones, simply the USB-Headphone adapter that is connected. Headphones may also be connected via Bluetooth.